# Finding means and medians across data frames in r

Tags: r, functional-programming

I have several data frames, `a` `b` `c` `d`, each with the same column names.  I want to find the mean and median of those data frames.  In other words, construct new `mean` and `median` data frames that are the same size as `a`, `b`, etc.

I could use a couple of `for` loops, but I bet there is a slick way of doing this using the R built-in functions that would be faster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following Josh Ulrich's answer, how about

```
library(abind)
apply(abind(a,b,c,d,along=3),c(1,2),median)
```

?
(Using `rowMeans` on the appropriate slice will still be faster than `apply`ing `mean` ... I think there is a `rowMedians` in the `Biobase` (Bioconductor) package if you really need speed?)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure JD's answer gives you exactly what you want, since the resulting object wouldn't be the same dimensions as `a`, `b`, etc.

Putting your data.frames into a list is a good start though.  Then you can subset each column into a new list, `cbind` that list into a matrix and use `apply` over it's rows.

```
a <- data.frame(rnorm(10), runif(10))
b <- data.frame(rnorm(10), runif(10))
c <- data.frame(rnorm(10), runif(10))
d <- data.frame(rnorm(10), runif(10))
myList <- list(a,b,c,d)
sapply(1:ncol(a), function(j) {  # median
  apply(do.call(cbind,lapply(myList,`[`,,j)), 1, median)
})
sapply(1:ncol(a), function(j) {  # mean
  apply(do.call(cbind,lapply(myList,`[`,,j)), 1, mean)
})
sapply(1:ncol(a), function(j) {  # faster mean
  rowMeans(do.call(cbind,lapply(myList,`[`,,j)))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you could string your data frames into a list of data frames, then use `lapply(myList, mean, ...)`

Comment: If you mean `lapply(c(a, b), mean)`, then that's not right.  That gives me the mean of each column individually, rather than across data frames.

Comment: ohhhhh... I didn't realize you wanted them all combined.